# Yandex карта на сайт

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть такой вопрос!

Есть каталог сервисных центров, когда в них заходишь, высвечивается место на карте, знаю как установить метку на карте и поставить его на сайт, это делается через сайт http://api.yandex.ru/maps/tools/constructor/

Но мне надо будет со своего сайта добавлять сервисы, точнее моему заказчику, и я думаю ему неудобно будет залезать на сайт яндекса находить место потом копировать этот код и ставлять на сайт. Не то, что не удобно даже, а этого ему ваще не надо.

Так вот мне надо чтобы была форма добавления сервиса и там стоит карта, и он по этой карте находит это место и нажимает просто добавить сервис.
Как это реализовать помогите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2):

Все на много проще, чем Вы думаете. Можно динамически устанавливать метки на карту, 
    var myMap;

```
    // Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init () {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {

            center:[50.785141, 21.178166],
            zoom:15
        });
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(99.785141, 19.178166], {
            // Чтобы балун и хинт открывались на метке, необходимо задать ей определенные свойства.
            balloonContentHeader: "Заголовок",
            balloonContentBody: "Текст внутри подсказки",
            balloonContentFooter: "Нижняя часть",
            hintContent: "подсказка"
        });

        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

    }
```

Comment: Объяснишь по подробней?

Comment: @Narik, ну смотри, перед этим всем ты подключаешь апи яндекса. Потом после загрузки страницы или в самый  низ ты суешь этот скрипт. Причем, 'map' это id дива, в котором должна находиться карта. В странице должен быть <div id='map'> </div>. 
Ну и все. Placemark это объект флажка. Все тут работает. Вставь на сайт и проверь.